# Calculate an integral solving a differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I've completely stuck with this problem:

Calculate:

$$ \int_0^{0.1} e^{-x^2} \,dx $$

solving the problem:

$$ y'(x)= e^{-x^2}, x \in [0, 0.1]$$
$$ y(0) = 0 $$

My doubt is just how to do it. I'm used to use aproximations (with Taylor, Euler, Runge-Kutta methods), but the statement always says "use X method to calculate an aproximate the value of an equation", but I have no idea about how to calculate the value of an integral.

Please, anybody could help me?
Thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE:

The complete statement says:

i)

We can see that numerical methods which are used to solve initial value problems, are also used to calculate integrals:

Demostrate that all initial value problem of the form:

$$ y'(x)= f(t,y(t)) , t \in [t_{0}, T]$$
$$ y(t_{0}) = y_{0} $$

is equivalent to the integral equation:

$$ y(t) = y_{0} + \int_{t_0}^{T} f(s,y(s)) \,ds $$

The second section ii) is the question I ask in the beggining.

I understand the second section is an application of the first section but the integral of the problem has no anylitic solution, so that...how to solve it?

I still don't see the solution even with your help and tips..

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to use numeric methods to get approximate value for this integral

Comment: Don't understand your ODE for $y(t)$ as it seems totally independent of $t$

Comment: You meant $y'(t) = e^{-t^{2}}$?

Comment: Perhaps your hint should be to find the antiderivative of $y'(t) = t e^{-t^2}$ as the antiderivative of $e^{-x^2}$ can be determined via the Error function but this is non-elementary.

Comment: I believe that this is an exercise in numerically approximating integrals

Comment: Expand the integrand with Taylor and integrate term-wise.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. You were right. I mistook the variable. I've to do it using an aproximation method but I have no idea about how to do it.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for the tip, but I think the teacher isn't looking we make the problem on that way. I never have seen that procedure before (as you say, it doesn't look as elementary).

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I though about doing that but I think this isn't the correct way because the statement says that I've to solve the differential equation to calculate the integral.

Comment: Please give the exact and complete question statement.

Comment: Your ODE does not have an elementary solution. I don't see what the exercise is doing in asking you to solve this, in order to approximate a definite integral.

Comment: @Kevin Actually the answer is in the question: the goal is to use a numerical methods to solve the ODE, to get the value of the definite integral.

Comment: This is backward. The midpoint and Heun ODE integration methods contain the midpoint and trapezium quadrature methods, RK4 was explicitly constructed to contain the Simpson method as quadrature method. As you have a quadrature problem, you should apply a quadrature method, the only question that remains is how fine the subdivision has to be to get below a given accuracy, but there is no accuracy level given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$0.1-\frac{0.1^3}{3}+\frac{0.1^5}{5\cdot2!}-\frac{0.1^7}{7\cdot3!}+\cdots$$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: what is the method asked to use ???

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: changing the comment after the fact, well done...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip but "I don't get it". Looks similar to the sin(x) Taylor development but has some differences....but my question is:.... I don't understand it :D
Sorry.

Comment: @cooper: I explained in a comment.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. Thanks Yves!